# Get specific object from Api

Tags: angular

I have a variable stored with an id.
I want to send a request to an API and back the object with this id.

with this code I get all the Objects. How can I do that?

```
findproduct(){
    return this.http.get('https://fakestoreapi.com/products').pipe(map((res:any)=>{return res;}))
    
  }
```

I tried the find() method but i get back a safeSubscriber

Comment: since reactivity is a key concept in angular I can't stress enough to read documentation and multiple articles across the web, until it will just click in your head. You can start [here](https://luukgruijs.medium.com/understanding-creating-and-subscribing-to-observables-in-angular-426dbf0b04a3) or [here](https://angular.io/guide/observables-in-angular) or [here](https://blog.angular-university.io/functional-reactive-programming-for-angular-2-developers-rxjs-and-observables/)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think that I found the solution for my problem. I had the user.id from previus component and i wanted to get API data based on this id.

This is the service's function:

```
  fetchproducts(){
return this.http.get('https://fakestoreapi.com/products').pipe(map((res:any)=>{return res;}))
```

}

this is the single product.ts

```
export class SingleproductComponent implements OnInit{
  user!:{id:number,title:string};
  Product:Product[]=[];

  constructor(private api:ApiService,private route:ActivatedRoute){} 

  ngOnInit(){
    this.user={
      id:this.route.snapshot.params['id'],
      title:this.route.snapshot.params['title'],
    }
    this.api.fetchproducts().pipe(map(res=>res.find((x:any)=> 
      this.user.id==x.id))).subscribe(x=>
        this.Product.push(new Product(x.id,x.title,x.description,x.image,x.price,x.rating,x.category)))

  }
}
```